# Make Woocommerce breadcrumbs show up using functions.php file

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

I updated my Woocommerce site to version 3.4.5 and the breadcrumbs disappeared. I didn't make any changes to the site except the update to Woocommerce right after updating to the newest WP 4.9.8 version. I've tried many different potential solutions I found online using the function, add_filter & add_action calls, but none have worked so far. Everything I've seen has been to make changes or make the breadcrumbs invisible. I want to leave them styled just as they were before the update (which was the default), but have them show up on the catalog and single product pages again. I think I can do this in the functions.php file of my theme, but I'm pretty new to php and nothing I've tried has forced them to show up. When I view the code via the browser I can't even find a class for breadcrumbs or anything currently, but the single product page within the new Woocommerce update looks just like the one from the version I updated from.

Any help is seriously appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your single-product.php contain this?

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
```

Comment: Yes it does contain that.

Comment: Please advise with site link so people can help you further.